# In LEFT JOIN, why did AND is not filtering out row in LEFT TABLE

Tags: mysql, left-join

Currently using MySQL 8.0

I want to keep only the rows in the control group in the left table.

My dummy data is:

```
CREATE table test1 (id int, ex_group varchar(50));
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES
(1, 'control'),
(2, 'control'),
(3, 'test'),
(4, 'test');
create table test2 (id int, gender varchar(50));
insert into test2 values 
(1,'f'),
(2,'f'),
(3,'m');
```

My query is:

```
select test1.*, test2.*
from test1
left join test2
on test1.id = test2.id
and test1.ex_group = 'control'
```

But the result is not what I expected because the 'test' is not filtered out in LEFT TABLE:

[image]

I understand I can use WHERE to filter out in LEFT TABLE, but I do not understand is why the filtering with AND works for RIGHT TABLE but not for LEFT TABLE.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e9398a8ebd9b5d96f1253c92827c4bc0

Comment: If you change "and" above, to "where" it should work.

Comment: "on" clause should be used only to control how tables are joined, not how result set is filtered.

Comment: @user1751825 By saying "filtering with ON and AND" in my question, I mean with `ON` used to control how tables are joined, why is `AND` following `ON` not filtering the LEFT TABLE. I want to know the logic behind, thanks!

Comment: Because "on" is only concerned with how the 2 tables are joined. It can't be used to filter the left table. That's what the "where" clause is for.

Comment: In this situation "inner join" would also work. This might be what you're really wanting to use.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: @ericzheng0404 It might be helpful to think about it in a different way. Rather than considering the "on" clause to be a way to filter the "right" table, think of it instead as just expressing how the tables are linked. This clause will typically match the foreign key relationship between the tables. Putting anything other than the "table1.id = table2.id" in an "on" clause is usually a mistake, and very often leads to unexpected results.

Comment: @user1751825 I understand now!! I'm giving you the props for this. Please make this comment as answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use where instead of condition in left join

```
select test1.*, test2.*
from test1
left join test2
on test1.id = test2.id
WHERE test1.ex_group = 'control'
```

Comment: I know `WHERE` works. I want to why using `AND` doesn't work.

Comment: @ericzheng0404 Consider what happens if you change the "on" to be "on 1=0". You'll still get all records from "test1". It's just how left joins work. With a left join you will always get all records from the left table, and only records from the right table that match the "on" clause.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).